# Best practice to search ingest-attachment from documents (2k+ documents with ingest-attachment)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am fetching the indexed documents from elastic search using Java API. But am getting `Null` as a response from elastic search when Index having more number of document like (2k+).

If index doesnt have more documents less than 500 something, the below Java API code is working properly.

More number of documents in Index, creating issue. ( Is that something like performance issue while fetching ?)

I used ingest-attachment processor plugin for attachment, i attached PDF in my documents.

But if i search with the same query using kibana with curl script am getting response, and am able to see the results in Kibana

Please find my java code below

```
private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment";
private final static String TYPE = "doc";

public static void main(String args[])
{
    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;

    try {
        restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    SearchRequest contentSearchRequest = new SearchRequest(ATTACHMENT); 
    SearchSourceBuilder contentSearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    contentSearchRequest.types(TYPE);
    QueryStringQueryBuilder attachmentQB = new QueryStringQueryBuilder("Activa"); 
    attachmentQB.defaultField("attachment.content");
    contentSearchSourceBuilder.query(attachmentQB);
    contentSearchSourceBuilder.size(50);
    contentSearchRequest.source(contentSearchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse contentSearchResponse = null;

    try {
        contentSearchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(contentSearchRequest); // returning null response
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    System.out.println("Request --->"+contentSearchRequest.toString());
    System.out.println("Response --->"+contentSearchResponse.toString());

    SearchHit[] contentSearchHits = contentSearchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    long contenttotalHits=contentSearchResponse.getHits().totalHits;
    System.out.println("condition Total Hits --->"+contenttotalHits);
```

Please find my script that am using in kibana., am getting response for the below script.

```
GET document_attachment/_search?pretty
{
  "query" :{
      "match": {"attachment.content": "Activa"}
  }
}
```

Please find the below search request from Java API

```
SearchRequest{searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH, indices=[document_attachment], indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[id=38, ignore_unavailable=false, allow_no_indices=true, expand_wildcards_open=true, expand_wildcards_closed=false, allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, forbid_closed_indices=true, ignore_aliases=false], types=[doc], routing='null', preference='null', requestCache=null, scroll=null, maxConcurrentShardRequests=0, batchedReduceSize=512, preFilterShardSize=128, source={"size":50,"query":{"match":{"attachment.content":{"query":"Activa","operator":"OR","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"lenient":false,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"boost":1.0}}}}}
```

Please find my mapping details

```
{
  "document_attachment": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "app_language": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "attachment": {
            "properties": {
              "author": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
              },
              "content_length": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "content_type": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "date": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "language": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "catalog_description": {
            "type": "text"
          },
         "fileContent": {
            "type": "text"
          }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please find my settings details

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/document_attachment
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "fileContent"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Am getting this error only when am trying to search based on `attachment.content` , If i search with some other field am able to get results.

Am using ElasticSearch 6.2.3 version

Please find the error below.

```
org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: entity content is too long [105539255] for the configured buffer limit [104857600]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.HeapBufferedAsyncResponseConsumer.onEntityEnclosed(HeapBufferedAsyncResponseConsumer.java:76)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.AbstractAsyncResponseConsumer.responseReceived(AbstractAsyncResponseConsumer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.responseReceived(MainClientExec.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseReceived(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.responseReceived(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:303)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.es.utility.DocumentSearch.main(DocumentSearch.java:88)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: Am getting this much information only., once started posting request, am getting this response., if the index having 2k + documents... same code is working with less than 500 documents index ..

Comment: Looks like the payload might be too big, you may want to filter the source to not bring back attachment.content part or use the scroll api to bring back paged chunks https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html